# How to get the last number of an integer input

Tags: java, exception, int, number-formatting

Binary to decimal converter without the use of built-in Java methods. It must do this conversion automatically. When I get the last number of the integer during input it gives me a number format exception.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter an 8-bit binary number:");
        int binary = keyboard.nextInt();
        int copyBinary = binary;
        int firstDigit = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(copyBinary).substring(0, 1));
        int secondDigit = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(copyBinary).substring(1, 2));
        int thirdDigit = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(copyBinary).substring(2, 3));
        int fourthDigit = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(copyBinary).substring(3, 4));
        int fifthDigit = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(copyBinary).substring(4, 5));
        int sixthDigit = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(copyBinary).substring(5, 6));
        int seventhDigit = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(copyBinary).substring(6, 7));
        int eigthDigit = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(copyBinary).substring(7));

        firstDigit = firstDigit*128;
        secondDigit = secondDigit*64;
        thirdDigit = thirdDigit*32;
        fourthDigit = fourthDigit*16;
        fifthDigit = fifthDigit*8;
        sixthDigit = sixthDigit*4;
        seventhDigit = seventhDigit*2;
        eigthDigit = eigthDigit*1;

        System.out.println(firstDigit+" "+secondDigit+" " +thirdDigit+" "+fourthDigit+" "+fifthDigit+" "+sixthDigit+" "+seventhDigit+" "+eigthDigit);

        System.out.println(copyBinary + " in decimal form is " + (firstDigit+secondDigit+thirdDigit+fourthDigit+fifthDigit+sixthDigit+seventhDigit+eigthDigit));
    }

}
```

Comment: Please minimize the problem until it is a [mcve]

Comment: By "last number of an integer input" do you mean digit? And what if you just enter fewer or greater than 8 bits?

Comment: yeah the last digit of the int i enter

Comment: I ran your code and got no exceptions...

Comment: You probably have a leading 0 that's being ignored by `parseInt()`.

Comment: the example is 01011001 with an output of 89

Comment: Why do not read the input as **string** from the keyboard? You could of use `charAt` for your calculation

Comment: how so? new programmer so I'm not efficient.

Comment: It's not about efficiency, it's about not mangling your data accidentally.  You're reading `01011001` from input as an `int`, which is `1011001`, which doesn't have an eighth digit to parse the way you're trying to.

Answer (score 1):

Leading zeros are ignored when you parse and format an `int`. The simplest solution is to keep the full value as a string and only then parse the individual digits:

```
String binary = keyboard.next();
int firstDigit = Integer.parseInt(binary.substring(0, 1));
// etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance friend!

Answer (score 0):

What I proposed in the comments is to read the whole input as **string** and then convert one character at the time to integer

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter an 8-bit binary number:");
String input = keyboard.nextLine();
// need to validate input here
int dec = 0;
for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++) {
   int x = Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(input.length()-1-i));
   dec += x * Math.pow(2, i);
}
System.out.println("For binary number " + input + " its decimal value is "  + dec);
```